# Marquee Text in Android Not Moving

Tags: android, text, textview, marquee

I am trying marquee text in android studio, but the text is not moving. My XML code below:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputText"
        android:layout_width="414dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Hello Walter!"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.969"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.23" />
```

I also have this in my onCreate in MainActivity.java:

```
        TextView outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);
        outputText.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Your code works properly but your text is too short. please use a long text. you'll see that it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! When I made the text a lot longer it worked.